# Why is the frame of my UIScrollView changing after making a call with ASIHTTPRequest?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, asihttprequest

I'm trying to figure out why the frame of a UIScrollView is changing after using ASIHTTPRequest. In the nib, the UIScrollView is set at `{{0, 0}, {320, 416}}` with the Top Bar on the view holding it set to be Navigation Bar.

Here's my code:

```
NSLog(@"Before URL %@", NSStringFromCGRect(mainScrollView.frame));    

__unsafe_unretained __block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
[request setDefaultResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setCompletionBlock:^{

    int responseCode = [request responseStatusCode];

    if(responseCode == 200) {

        NSLog(@"200 %@", NSStringFromCGRect(mainScrollView.frame));
```

The output I get in the console is:

`Before URL {{0, 0}, {320, 416}}`

`200 {{0, -44}, {320, 416}}` <----- Why the -44??

Can anyone explain why this might be happening?

Comment: Are there any adjustments being made to its superview? Would there be any other method that would adjust the size of any view elements?

Comment: @barfoon: Wild guess! Anything to do with ASIHTTPRequest controlling the network activity indicator in the status bar? Might be worth investigating or forcing off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to change setting in nib files.?

Check the autosizing of scroll view in nib.

Comment: This solved the problem. Still would love to know why that happens.